# jsonp callback function not getting called

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jsonp, dotcms

I am doing a cross domain AJAX call with dataType as jsonp. I have set the Jsoncallback querystring parameter in the URL. However, the callback function is not getting called at all and instead the page gets redirected to itself.

The AJAX call is basically hitting a dot CMS service which returns below response when I tested it in browser directly:

```
myfunction({'state':'MEL', 'plan':'true' })
```

Here, "myfunction" is the string which I pass as the value of Jsoncallback parameter in URL

Here is my AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
  url:"http://website.hostname.com/validatepostcode.dot?postcode="+encodeURIComponent(thepostcode)+ "&Jsoncallback=parseResponse",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  async: false,
  crossDomain:true
  });


function parseResponse(data)
{
 alert(data);
}
```

Am I missing any parameter in  AJAX call? Or there may be something wrong at service side?

Comment: The dot CMS service reads the querystring parameter which I send and returns the response in jsonp format wrapped in that function name like myfunction({'state':'MEL', 'plan':'true' })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) jQuery function has specific configuration options for supplying the name of the callback function that seem to be missing from the code.

By setting `dataType: 'jsonp'` jQuery

> Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback

which is causing a problem as you are also adding a callback function in the `url` value.

To override this you can add the `jsonp` option which:

> Override the callback function name in a jsonp request. This value will be used instead of 'callback' in the 'callback=?' part of the query string in the url.

You can also specify the `data` as a separate option (see [**Sending Data to the server**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server)) which I have also added below.

The following code should correctly use `parseResponse()` as the callback function.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://website.hostname.com/validatepostcode.dot',
  type: 'get',
  data: {postcode: encodeURIComponent(thepostcode)},
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'parseResponse'
});
```

Comment: Thanks..i will try it and let u know.

Comment: Thanks @andyb. It helps. Now getting one more issue. After the execution goes into callback function, I am trying to post the form by setting its action attribute dnamically. And this is not happening. It always redirecting to self. I will raise separate post for this.